# Codeigniter: Getting a uri string without the first segment

Tags: codeigniter, uri, segment

I have some code in Codeigniter where I have the language code in the first segment of the URI, and I would like to know how to obtain a URI string without the first segment independently of the number of segments the URI might have.

Example:
Having this URL:

```
http://example.com/en/seg1/seg2
```

This `$this->uri->uri_string()` will result in `en/seg1/seg2`

But what I want is only `seg1/seg2/etc..`

I tried using the `for` loop to get all segments except the first, but it outputs only 0, like in:

`for ($i=2; $i <= $numsegments; $i++) {
   $string += $this->uri->segment($i);
}`

I'm out of options.
I appreciate your help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the "en/" using str_replace

```
$string=str_replace("","en/",$this->uri->segment($i));
```

**UPDATE**

```
$pos= strpos('/',$this->uri->segment($i)); //returns position of your first /
$string = substr($this->uri->segment($i),$pos+1);
```

Comment: That can't be, because the first segment in my case is the language code, and it can also be anything, so hardcoding it is not an option.

Comment: The language code can be anything? doesnt sound very safe. Surely there is a list of expected values?

Comment: @Mike Miller Yes, I have a list of languages and its codes to be checked against.

Comment: So you can do a string replace using your list of accepted language codes passed in as an array. If the str_replace doesnt find anything you know that a dodgy language code has been used.